# ANDROID, How to implement Web content filtering

Tags: android, web-content, emm, android-device-owner

I have an application that is Device-owner and now I need to create Web content filtering. What is the best option for that? For example, if I blocked [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com), a user can't open that URL in any web browser on an android device.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.